# Braille in android (IDE: Eclipse)

Tags: android

I am writing an application in android to convert english text to braille. How can I do this? Is there any font that I can download to convert english letters entered by user to Braille or is there any other way to do this?

Any support provided will indeed be appreciated!

Comment: please don't ask questions twice

Comment: possible duplicate of [Braille support in android Application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14378006/braille-support-in-android-application)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many braille fonts on http://www.fontspace.com/category/braille.

But what do you really want to do ? Only display an equivalent in braille ? or make a tactile gadget to translate the text in braille ?

To add a font, use :

```
Typeface typface=Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/YOURFONT.ttf");
```

and put your font in the asset directory

Comment: In my app, user gives a file in english as input which is translated to braille equivalent.

Comment: I don't really know how works braille, I remember there are different braille (different grades ?), and one on these only represent each character with a braille symbol, no ? For this case, you only need to change the font of your string with a braille font